# ¿Cómo se puede programar una barra de video o de progreso sin utilizar el comando "controls" de la etiqueta de video?

Tags: video, progressbar

Estoy haciendo un reproductor de video en `HTML` y necesito extraer todas las funciones de la etiqueta "`controls`" de video. Ya cuento con el <kbd>botón</kbd> de "**Play**", "**Pause**", "**FullScreen**" pero me faltan más funciones como la barra de progreso.

Answer (score 0):

En cuanto a la barra de progreso tienes que documentarte en las dos aspectos que son mostrar el tiempo y usar la barra para desplazarte en el video.

Aqui te coloco un link con informacion util para tu pregunta:

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp

Tambien te hice un codigo de ejemplo para la visualizacion de una barra de progreso usando el input type="range" el cual sirve de base para tu pregunta.

incluyo codigo HTML / JavaScript.

```js
  
    // declaracion de variables 
    var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");

    // se ejecuta cuando esta funcionado la barra de progreso
    vid.ontimeupdate = function() {
        var posicion =vid.currentTime; // posicion actual 
        var max = vid.duration; // duracion maxima del video

        // poner valores en los atributos del input range 
        // para usar como barra de progreso
        document.getElementById('barra').setAttribute("max", max);
        document.getElementById('barra').value = posicion;
    };
```

```html
    <video id="myVideo" width="320" height="176" controls>
        <source src="videoprueba.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      </video>
</body>
<p>Barra de Progreso</p>
<form>
    <input type="range" name="points" min="0" max="10" id="barra">
</form>
```